# How to encrypt large data with travis for Node environment

Tags: travis-ci

I'm trying to add NODE variable to travis through travis encrypt feature. However, the text is too large that I cannot run it.

```
travis encrypt super=large-text --add
```

[image]

I tried to look into the instruction through [Travis Encryption Files](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/). However, it doesn't show the content of the encrypt file. I'm not sure how to encrypt a large variable to travis. Please help to take a look at this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to Travis CI Dashboard and add your secret variables.